# @Interceptors ignored in Wicket subclass WebPage

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wicket, cdi, wicket-7

I have an external CDI Component (jee6) which I use as a Maven dependency.

This component contains an Object A , which when Injected in a subclass from a Wicket WebPage works as expected. So far So good.

This CDI component also provides some convenience Interceptors. When in I use these Wickets seems to ignore them.

When I use these Interceptors in Non-Wicket java classes the work as expeted. Anyone who might have an idea of whats going on here?

```
public class EnterExitMethodInterceptor {

@Inject
@Technical
Logger logger;

/**
 * Methode welke logt dat je een methode binnenkomt en een methode verlaat.
 * 
 * @param ic
 *            {@link InvocationContext}.
 * @return {@link Object}
 * @throws {@link
 *             Exception}
 */
@AroundInvoke
public Object writeEnterExitMethod(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Enter Method: " + ic.getMethod().getName());
    Object o = ic.proceed();
    logger.info("Exit Method: " + ic.getMethod().getName());
    return o;

   }
 }
```

The Interceptor is invoked by annotating the method with

```
    @Interceptors(EnterExitMethodInterceptor.class)
```

Comment: Perhaps the beans.xml with the interceptors is missing in your jar's META-INF directory?

Comment: @svenmeier My beans.xml is empty, but injecting and using Object A works as expected, But I gave it a try. with the same result. On onther places i didn't use the Interceptor binding and it just worked, Here I used with and without binding and it failed.

Comment: I'm not using that module, so I don't know whether interceptors should work. Perhaps it is not supported they way https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-cdi/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/cdi/NonContextualManager.java does the injection.

Comment: @svenmeier seems You are right. Somewhere in the doc I remember Wicket injection in not-JEE conainer is limited (in Java SE style). Sorry, I can not give link